# My custom get_the_excerpt() can't get excerpt by ID

Tags: php, wordpress, function

On my single.php page I am trying to create a function to give me a custom length excerpt of a specific post by ID.

Below are my two functions I am running.

```
/* Custom get_the_excerpt to allow getting Post excerpt by ID */
function custom_get_the_excerpt($post_id) {
  global $post;
  $save_post = $post;
  $post = get_post($post_id);
  $output = get_the_excerpt($post);
  $post = $save_post;
  return $output;
}

/* Change Excerpt length */
function excerpt($num, $post_id = '') {
    $limit = $num+1;
    $excerpt = explode(' ', custom_get_the_excerpt($post_id), $limit);
    array_pop($excerpt);
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt)."&#8230";
    echo $excerpt;
}
```

What I'm using to call the function.

```
<?php $previous = get_previous_post();
echo excerpt('30', $previous -> ID); ?>
```

The issue I am running into is $post is giving me the previous post information however when I pass that into get_the_excerpt it returns the current post excerpt rather than the previous post excerpt.

EDIT

Changed function to this after several people told me I can just pass the $post_id to get_the_excerpt()

```
/* Change Excerpt length */
function excerpt($num, $post_id = '') {
    $limit = $num+1;
    $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt($post_id), $limit);
    array_pop($excerpt);
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt)."&#8230";
    echo $excerpt;
}
```

Still no change.

Comment: Is it a typo that you have spaces around "->" in `echo excerpt('30', $previous -> ID); ` I'm pretty sure that's not going to work - and I suspect that makes $post_id undefined in your custom call - so it all uses the current $post. Also, I am pretty sure you don't have to bother with `get_post` - just pass your post_id to get_the_excerpt should work.

Comment: No change with no spaces around "->"

Also you are right I could just pass $post_id but that doesn't change the issue either. :(

Answer (score 2):

Adding in setup_postdata($post); fixed my issue.

```
function custom_get_the_excerpt($post_id) {
  global $post;
  $save_post = $post;
  $post = get_post($post_id);
  setup_postdata($post);
  $output = get_the_excerpt($post);
  wp_reset_postdata();
  $post = $save_post;
  return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following function get two parmeters:
- $num : the number of character you would display
- $post_id: the ID of the post you want to get the content

and:
- if in the content there is the  mark, return the text until it
- if $num is = 0 return the content until the first full stop
otherwise return a number of character specified on $num adding "..." at the end of the string

```
function my_custom_excerpt($num = 0,$post_id=''){
$post=get_post($post_id);
$content=$post->post_content;
if(strpos($content,'&lt;!&#8211;more&#8211;&gt;')>0){
    return substr($content,0,strpos($content,'&lt;!&#8211;more&#8211;&gt;'));
}else{
    if($num===0){
        return substr($content,0,strpos($content,'.')+1);
    }else{
        return substr($content,0,$num).((strlen($content)>$num)?"...":"");
    }
}
}
```